# Problem with comparing two images using imagemagick in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, imagemagick

I am using ImageMagick tool in C# to identity two images are simiral or not.

```
    var img1 = new ImageMagick.MagickImage("D:\\test\\img1.jpg");
    var img2 = new ImageMagick.MagickImage("D:\\test\\img2.jpg");
    var img3 = new ImageMagick.MagickImage("D:\\test\\img3.jpg");

    // Return 1 Means Similar Image
    if (img2.Compare(img1) == 1)
    {
        // Here I want to delete Duplicate Image
    }
    if (img3.Compare(img1) == 1)
    {
        // Here I don't want to delete because both image different
    }
```

Here are images in sequence.

[image: img1.jpg]

[image: img2.jpg]

[image: img3.jpg]

Please help me with this where I am wrong.

OR

Suggest any other best and quick solution to compare images visually in c#.

Comment: Compare is not scale independent. So if two images are the same subject but one is smaller than the other, the compare will indicated not the same.